# How to solve moment not defined error in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

all I want to filter the items like (Start and End Date)  which are based on `invoice_date` using the date range functionality in meanjs app.

- My problem is the date filter function are working perfectly in `plunker and my localHost production` but  while pushing to server it's showing only up to `May month` data's if some `invoice_date` values date is been `2017-08-24 and 2017-07-27' these data is not displaying in table, I don't know where I did the mistake and what I have missed it ..... [My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/25sDpSmciSfQ7nC7x1a7?p=preview)
- Please look at my plunker to reference.
- I Have displaying `invoice_date`, so this is the field I want to use for filtering.
- So what I exactly looking for, I want to filter the `invoice_date` as start date and end date : **for example:-** if we select start date like `24-05-2017` and end date is `24-08-2017` in table this two transaction only need to display or filter... so I have used date range filter to achieve this solution, but in server it's not working for us please help.
- In my server if I select `end date` as today's date all data's are showing on the table, so I think the problem is based on these fields `$scope.from = new Date(2014, 04, 30);
  $scope.to = new Date(2019, 08, 25);`
- [image] in terminal this error occurs if we solve this error definitely will get the solution, I have tried it myself but I unable to solve this... so please help to solve this problem.

**Controller:**

```
 .filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, dateKey, from, to) {
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            return !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isBefore(moment(from))
            && !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isAfter(moment(to));
        });
    };
})
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
```

**Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="data in  record | dateRange : 'invoice_date' : from : to"
```

- I have created plunker for reference:- [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/25sDpSmciSfQ7nC7x1a7?p=preview)

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. However, what I did notice is that ng script reference took forever to load. You might want to use a `cdnjs.cloudflare` link for it as well.

Comment: I don't see where you're injecting moment?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have used this 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js', only in my project...but again the above screen shot error is showing...please help me thanks for advance

Comment: @rrd please look at my plunker for reference

Comment: I did, still don't see it being injected anywhere there. You've got a script tag yes, but moment is (at least in the Angular code I work with daily) injected as a dependency.

Comment: It is not enough that you have the script tag. It will load the script into your app. But you should inject it into your controller.

Comment: Hi rrd and kkk  I am new to angular js, in my project I have given this  link  'cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js&#‌​39  into `all.js` and `production.js` so if you guys have any example and solution please let me know if possible update my plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks and how and where I need to inject in my controller. please help me thanks...

Comment: hi, guys Any Update? on the same please update my plunker or provide a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out to configure & inject into your module. Please use the steps excerpt from [here](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

1. First of all install the moment library using bower

   `bower install angular-moment --save`
2. Then include the following:

   `moment.js` & `angular-moment.js`
3. Configure in your module like this

   `var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);`

   Use in your controller like as

   `angular.module('fooApp')
       .controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', 'moment', function ($scope, moment) {
           $scope.exampleDate = moment().hour(8).minute(0).second(0).toDate();
       }]);`

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by adding this line in my index.html file please add this line in index.html and run again.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What line? You did not give an example.